# fabricjs angular 4 Display fabricjs canvas list dynamically

Tags: angular, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to display my layouts using fabricjs canvas. I receive layout list from server on ngOnInit which I am able to display but once new layouts are added to my layouts list dom gets re-rendered but resizes the old layouts but not the new one.
I tried to google but couldn't find something.
Following is my html code to render layoutsList:

```
    <div class="flex-container" *ngIf="layoutsList.length > 0">
      <div class="disable" *ngFor="let el of layoutsList; let i = index">
         <canvas id='canvas{{i}}' height="200px" width="230px"></canvas> {{i}}
         <label class="btn btn-primary" (click)="changeLayout(el)">
          Edit
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteLayout(i, el)">
         Delete
        </label>
      </div> 
    </div>

<button class="btn-primary">
  <i class="fa fa-plus" (click)="addNewLayout()">  Add New Layout</i>
</button>
```

Comment: whta is index in html? and what is the canvas element id you are assigning in DOM?

Comment: @Durga I have a layoutsList which has layouts in it and every time user add a new layout it adds to layoutsList array. I was creating layouts using fabric js canvas so used index as id of canvases. after debugging bit more i saw that it never assign id to the canvas on push.  this.canvases[id] = new fabric.Canvas('canvas' + id) create canvas with != id

Comment: and index is current item in the iterable.

Comment: Is it the same what you have canvas id on dom , and you are initialising fabricjs canvas with same id?

Comment: yes id's are same but for some reason the canvas is not rendering on dom eventhough got content on the canvas when inspecting or logging to console.

Comment: Can you make a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/p9vMvlzEwUOOlcP2FsUG/)?

Comment: I am not sure if plunker would be good idea as needed to mock up stuff and I am new to this

Comment: @Durga I solved that part but now when I redraw fabric js canvases, the exiting canvases resizes meanwhile the new added once not.

Comment: It's hard for me to guess. How you are resizing canvases?

Comment: @Durga I am not resizing but when it detects any changes in the layoutsList it redraw the canvas list but canvases get resizes expect the last new canvas.